# LiipImagineBundle + Symfony media from web url doesn't work?

Tags: symfony, liipimaginebundle

I use Symfony 2.0.19 with LiipImagineBundle

I want to use a filter for an image from the web (for example: http://images.apple.com/retail/fifthavenue/images/fifthavenue_hero.jpg)  but the `imagine_filter` seems not to work with image from the web.

Does somebody have an explication?

config.yml:

```
liip_imagine:
    filter_sets:
        thumbnail:
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [300, 300], mode: outbound }
```

HTML

```
<img src="{{ asset('http://images.apple.com/retail/fifthavenue/images/fifthavenue_hero.jpg') |imagine_filter('thumbnail') }}" />
```

Output:

There is no image processed :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discussed with the author of LiipImagineBundle and for the moment it's not possible to do it.

You have to use a hack, **I propose you another approach**:

1. download to your server the image you want to use
2. use your filter
3. delete the tmp file

See ya